# gas error on semaphore deployment

Tags: sepolia, semaphore

I'm using [semaphore deployment doc](https://docs.semaphore.pse.dev/deployed-contracts) for its's deployment and I have error for gas usage, but I checked everything and it's ok. also, it works with no problem in hardhat node.

command:
`yarn deploy --semaphore 0x3889927F0B5Eb1a02C6E2C20b39a1Bd4EAd76131 --group 42 --network sepolia`

error:

`Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="execution reverted", method="estimateGas"`

`reason: 'execution reverted', code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT', method: 'estimateGas',`

Answer (score 0):

in testnet group Id 42 already exist. **use different number**.

for example, `yarn deploy --semaphore 0x3889927F0B5Eb1a02C6E2C20b39a1Bd4EAd76131 --group 15162 --network sepolia`